# My requirement is to send notification messages by using Microsoft Graph Restful API to MS-Team user

Tags: microsoft-teams

What is needed : My requirement is to send notification messages by using Microsoft Graph Restful API to MS-Team user. The conversation should be private and hence can be read by only addressed  recipient.

What I have done so far : 
•   Created Office 365 tenant and added test users. 
•   The users are able to send messages among them. 
•   I have created .net sample by using Graph API which can do following list actions
o   Create team
o   Add Channel
o   Add users
o   Send messages to Channel of specific team

Comment: Thanks For your quick response.

Basically I want to send message on MS-Team from Asp.net C# application. The message should be delivered to specific user on MS Team not at Team channel. Any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API to send a proactive notification to a user in 1:1 scope is currently not supported. You could try sending a [proactive message using Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive). Please let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks For your quick response.

Comment: Thanks For your quick response.

Basically I want to send message on MS-Team from Asp.net C# application. The message should be delivered to specific user on MS Team not at Team channel. Any suggestion will help.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, please try sending a proactive message using Bots.